# Lexicography in Java

Tags: java

If I wanted to simply replace a letter or a number with one immediately preceding it, how would I go about that?
For example, I wanted to replace the letter 'c' with 'b' in my code, or 3 with 2. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

The "char" type is numeric, and you can subtract one from it to get the answer you want. Work out what you want to do with '0' or 'a'.

Comment: This works for ASCII, but be careful with UTF8 encoded characters.

Comment: Also remember edge cases such as `a`.

Comment: So for example, if I had char letter = 'b', could I do letter = letter-1?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Per Jason’s point, `letter = 'é' ; letter = letter-1` isn’t going to give you 'd', of course. You will need to ensure you really are looking at an ordinary letter or digit.